# Download apps From Play Store Forced to stop

Tags: android

Recently I have upload a apps [Here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pavel.simplecounterpluss).When I was run my apps in my eclipse emulator and my android phone it was fine.
But when I download my apps from Google play store and run my apps it forced to stop why this happening I do't know Please make some answer.
What is the wrong about it?

this is my logcat

```
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2391)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:151)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1335)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5511)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1029)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:796)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.pavel.simplecounterpluss.MainActivity
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1069)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-10 16:19:12.953: E/AndroidRuntime(10619):    ... 11 more
08-10 16:19:12.963: E/EmbeddedLogger(411): Application Label: Simple Counter Pluss
```

Comment: What do you mean "forced to stop"? If it crashes, post the error log please

Comment: When I run this apps it show that Unfortunately,simple counter plus has stop.@Jim

Comment: Can you plug your device into your machine and see the logcat for it? If so, post it.

Comment: When I run this apps in my android phone it's fine but I upload this in Google play and when I download this apps from play store and try to run it then it shows  Unfortunately,simple counter plus has stop.@Jim

Comment: I realize that. After you download it from Google Play, you can still plug your phone into your dev machine and get the logcat from it. Can you post that logcat?